# Python & Pandas: Errors in pulling dataframa data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm seeking to run a script with Python and Pandas that pulls data from a csv and then uploads that data as grades and comments via the CanvasAPI wrapper. I've successfully run this script before with different csv's with no difficulty, but I'm encountering an error with a new csv, and baffled as to why.

Here is the structure of a csv that uploads successfully, `Test2.csv`, with the key column highlighted in red ([available here via FileDropper](http://www.filedropper.com/test2_2)):

[image]

When I run the following script below, all this is successfully uploaded via API to my local instance of Canvas. `

```
from canvasapi import Canvas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Test2.csv")

canvas = Canvas(API_URL, API_KEY)

course = canvas.get_course(9997)

assignment = course.get_assignment(80227)

userlist = [canvas.get_user(user) for user in df['user_id']] # <<<< error lists this as the problem line

scorelist = df['total_score']
length2 = len(scorelist)

scores = []
for x in range(length2):
    scores.append(scorelist[x])


for i in range(len(userlist)):
    submission = assignment.get_submission(userlist[i]) # <<<< connected with line above
    submission.edit(submission={'posted_grade': scores[i]})
```

The code above works well with the above `Test2.csv`. However, when I substitute the csv below, `Control.csv`, things get wonky. Again, see highlighted column in red. ([File available via FileDropper](http://www.filedropper.com/control_1))

[image]

The headers for both csv's are identical (right?). But when I run the new script I receive the following error associated to `userlist = [canvas.get_user(user) for user in df['user_id']]:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\2021628-11980-1wqutpl.gh26", line 23, in <module>
    userlist = [canvas.get_user(user) for user in df['user_id']]   File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\2021628-11980-1wqutpl.gh26", line 23, in <listcomp>
    userlist = [canvas.get_user(user) for user in df['user_id']]   File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\canvas.py", line 1224, in get_user
    response = self.__requester.request(   File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\requester.py", line 255, in request
    raise ResourceDoesNotExist("Not Found") canvasapi.exceptions.ResourceDoesNotExist: Not Found
```

Any guesses on what's going on here? All assistance gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I discovered the issue. The second csv is for a test user, and for some reason Canvas won't accept API grade submissions for the account. I'll explore the documentation for more.